# Sort NSMutableArray for a key with float datatype

Tags: sorting, nsmutablearray

I have a NSMutableArray with data:

```
Name ... Male ... Age ... Point
("David"..."Male"...18...7.25)
("Mary"..."Female"...16...20.50)
("Kend"..."Male"...17...4.50)
("Frank"..."Male"...25...27.50)
("Cain"..."Female"...28...2.25)
("Sims"..."Female"...17...10.50)
```

...

I want to sort this NSMutableArray by key Point. I tried:

```
NSSortDescriptor *aSortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"Point" ascending:NO];
[self.arrayPupils sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:aSortDescriptor]];
```

and output:

```
David/Male/18/7.25
Kend/Male/17/4.50
Frank/Male/25/27.50
Mary/Female/16/20.50
Cain/Female/28/2.25
Sims/Female/17/10.50
```

But expected result are:

```
Frank/Male/25/27.50
Mary/Female/16/20.50
Sims/Female/17/10.50
David/Male/18/7.25
Kend/Male/17/4.50
Cain/Female/28/2.25
```

Help me pls... Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your sort is sorting by Age. You need to instead sort by "Point" to get that output.

Comment: Don't see value of Age. Let's see Point. They sorted by "alphabet": 7.xx > 4.xx > 1x.xx
Example:
9.25 >
826.50 >
82.50 >
8.50 >
7.50 >
...